# Threading Images

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was wondering how to change the Rectangles into images when pressing a button I don't know how to do it myself :(

[image]

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th = new Thread(thread);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void thread()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 4), new Rectangle(rdm.Next(0, this.Width), rdm.Next(0, this.Height), 20, 20));
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Complete a");
        }
```

Comment: [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) : _"Draws the specified Image at the specified location and with the original size."_ (You can size it in overloads. List inside.)

Comment: `CreateGraphics()` is TEMPORARY.  You need to PERSIST the state of each Rectangle() in a structure (maybe a `List<Rectangle>`?) that is stored at Form level, then repaint each one in the `Paint()` event using the supplied `e.Graphics`.  To change them into pictures, you'd toggle a flag and `Invalidate()` causing a repaint.  This time in the `Paint()` event you'd see the changed flag state and draw images instead of rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

by inserting this code :  Image img = Image.FromFile(@"picture.jpg");
and change DrawRectangle into DrawImage works but it seems it is stuck in one positionon the form. The image supposedly must appear in different/random position in the form.

```
public void thread()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(img, 70, 70, 70, 70);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
    
                MessageBox.Show("Complete a");
            }
```